# Batch send data to COM1 and other COM ports

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

I wrote a script that writes strings to com port and store the return in a text file.

```
mode COM1 Baud=9600 Parity=N Data=8 Stop=1 dtr=off rts=off

echo message>COM1
```

it works really well, as long as I don't change the com port.
i renamed COM1 (device Manager) to COM22  - not working anymore
i tried USB/Serial Adapter (COM7) - not working

it doesn't take e.g. "COM22" as an port...it takes it as an file (creates a file COM22)

just why       ?

thanks a lot!

Comment: This from how not to name a file. Do not use the following reserved device names for the name of a file: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid these names followed by an extension, for example, NUL.tx7.
Windows NT:  CLOCK$ is also a reserved device name.

Comment: this means, sending and receiving is only possible with ports from COM1 to COM9?

Comment: Yes, unless a thirdparty vxd (a virtual device driver (they are 16 bit) that are no longer written) has added more.

Comment: okay great, thank you! I need to deal with 1-9...:/

Comment: Please note that "COM22" is just a name for a serial COM port which can be changed at any time via device manager. You will find there "COMX (in use)". But `in use` means that this "COMx" name was once in the past assigned to a serial device and therefore reserved for that device in case of ever plug it again. So you can select also "COMX (in use)" for a serial port as long as this COM is not really active at the moment in which case the port would be displayed in device manager. The reserved COM numbers can be safely reset by modifying a value in Windows registry.